# Variation of refractive index with increase in salt concentration

Tags: refraction

Is there a study which shows a table or data of this variation of the refractive index?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there is. Like [Remote monitoring of water salinity by using side-polished fiber-optic U-shaped sensor](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261419326_Remote_monitoring_of_water_salinity_by_using_side-polished_fiber-optic_U-shaped_sensor) by **Dragan Z. Stupar, Jovan S. Bajić, Ana V. Joža, Bojan M. Dakić, Miloš P. Slankamenac, Miloš B. Živanov, Edvard Cibula**. They give such graph :

[image]

There probably exists research of other materials refractive index variation as $n=n(C)$